# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on MSys2 in Sphinx

Tags: python, ssl, python-sphinx, msys2

On MSys2 I was trying to build the HTML version of the Sphinx-based documentation with `make html` and got the following error:

```
loading intersphinx inventory from http://docs.python.org/objects.inv...
WARNING: intersphinx inventory 'http://docs.python.org/objects.inv' not fetchable due to <class 'urllib2.URLError'>: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the common certificates has helped (see the `pacman -Ss cert` output for available variants and architectures):

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates
```